# How to set alignment in a JavaFX TextField?

Tags: javafx-2

I need to set allignment of the text in a TextField to right. There is no such under TextField.
Anybody knows how to set alignment in a textfield in javaFX 2.0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently It does not have a support on text field alignment. 
I reported this issue to javafx jira team and this feature will be added in version 2.1.

Here is the link.
http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18410?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: your link is broken

Answer (score 8):

In JavaFX 2.0, it may not have been possible, but it *is* in JavaFX 2.1 and ownward using the [alignment property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#alignmentProperty).

##### Programmatically

```java
textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
```

or

##### via FXML

```xml
<TextField ... alignment="CENTER_RIGHT"/>
```

or

##### via [CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textfield)

```css
    .text-field {
         -fx-alignment: center-right;   
    }
```

### [Possible values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html)

| Programmatic/FXML | CSS | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `BASELINE_CENTER` | `baseline-center` | Represents positioning on the baseline vertically and on the center horizontally. |
| `BASELINE_LEFT` | `baseline-left` | Represents positioning on the baseline vertically and on the left horizontally. |
| `BASELINE_RIGHT` | `baseline-right` | Represents positioning on the baseline vertically and on the right horizontally. |
| `BOTTOM_CENTER` | `bottom-center` | Represents positioning on the bottom vertically and on the center horizontally. |
| `BOTTOM_LEFT` | `bottom-left` | Represents positioning on the bottom vertically and on the left horizontally. |
| `BOTTOM_RIGHT` | `bottom-right` | Represents positioning on the bottom vertically and on the right horizontally. |
| `CENTER` | `center` | Represents positioning on the center both vertically and horizontally. |
| `CENTER_LEFT` | `center-left` | Represents positioning on the center vertically and on the left horizontally. |
| `CENTER_RIGHT` | `center-right` | Represents positioning on the center vertically and on the right horizontally. |
| `TOP_CENTER` | `top-center` | Represents positioning on the top vertically and on the center horizontally. |
| `TOP_LEFT` | `top-left` | Represents positioning on the top vertically and on the left horizontally. |
| `TOP_RIGHT` | `top-right` | Represents positioning on the top vertically and on the right horizontally. |