# How I align TextField Value in 'center' using Jspdf during export

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My js Code is...

```
 var textField = new TextField();
                textField.Rect = [13, 47, 180, 10];
                textField.multiline = false;
                textField.V = "461 Dean Apartments";
                textField.T = "TestTextBox";
                doc.addField(textField);
```

below is the example of my editable Pdf field where I want to show "461 Dean Apartments" in the center or justify.

Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKgEx.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399026/how-to-set-alignment-in-a-javafx-textfield) answers your question ?

Comment: Let me check brother @Lyes

Comment: I am using javascript its not working in javaScript

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the actual approach

textField.Q = 1; for Center alignment and
textField.Q = 2; for Right alignment

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `textAlign` function

```
  textField.textAlign = "center"
```

Here is the [documentation](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-AcroForm-AcroFormTextField.html).

According to this [source](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_acroform.js.html#line1543) it seems you can also set it using `defineProperty`

```
   Object.defineProperty(textField, "textAlign", {
        get: function(value){
            return "center"
        },
        set: function(value){
            return "center"
        },
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
    }
```

Comment: Index:396 Uncaught TypeError: textField.textAlign is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Index:396)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.10.2.js:5109)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.10.2.js:4780)
(anonymous) @ Index:396
dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5109
elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4780

Comment: textAlign() is not a function

Comment: I have used this textField.textAlign=" center" but it's not working for me

Comment: Ok, I modified my answer, check it please.