# JavaFX Spinner - How to align the text inside the spinner if the arrows are on left and right?

Tags: javafx, spinner

So I have this Spinner which is used for pagination. Its style class looks like below:

```
Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(1,20,1);
spinner.getStyleClass().add(Spinner.STYLE_CLASS_SPLIT_ARROWS_HORIZONTAL);
```

So now the spinner appears with arrows on the left and right sides of the number. However, the text is aligned to the left of the spinner always. Say even if I have some width for the spinner (ex. 200px or something) the number displayed in the spinner is always next to the left arrow. I would like to know how to set it to the center of the Spinner.

This is what I tried in CSS:

```
.spinner > .text-field
{
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}

.spinner
{
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}

.spinner > text
{
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: Using resources such as the `modena.css` file in the JavaFX installation and the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) is preferable to trying to guess CSS selectors and attributes.  If you are really stuck, then you can also try [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view).

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
.spinner > .text-field
{
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
```

The `-fx-text-alignment` property determines how multi-line text is aligned (i.e. the alignment of one line of text relative to another line). To align overall content, use `-fx-alignment`.

Comment: For additional info, see: [How to set alignment in a JavaFX TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53599849/1155209). You can also search the file `modena.css` in your JavaFX installation for `.spinner` and you can see that the text field is referenced by `.spinner > .text-field`, as in this answer.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks a lot, both of you